# Started or has started

Tags: past-tense, present-perfect

> Life **started** in a simple organisms .

Can **has started** can be used instead of **started?** Then how are the meanings different?
Because life is still going on, can i use present perfect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. “Has started” can only be used for the *recent* past. Life started many years ago, so the present perfect tense is inappropriate here. Even if life still exists now, you’re only talking about when it *started*, which was long ago in the past, so you should use the simple past tense.

Comment: Then, how about this "Humans have survived in this planet for a long time " Despite its long time  distance,  "has survived" does not sound awkward to me. What factor is different?

Comment: *on* this planet, not *in* this planet. Also- *organism* (no “s”). But good point about the recent past- this is not always the rule. “Have survived” is fine because the “surviving” started at one point in the past and continues to this day. “Started” is not something that can continue over a long period of time- the “starting” happened in the past and that was it.

Comment: Wow so clear to me! Can i ask one more? "This week a new semester started/has started in most schools " In this recent case, then, past and present perfect are interchangeable or have different meanings?

Comment: Yes, in this case you're talking about the recent past ("this week") so either the present perfect or simple past would be appropriate. The meaning is the same.

Comment: @Mixolydian Can you provide a reference for present perfect being appropriate only for the recent past?

Comment: @nasch it's not true that present perfect is only appropriate for the recent past in general, but I don't think the verb phrase "has started" works if the "starting" was a long time ago. When you say "It has started" the implication is "It has started recently" or "It has just started". As long as the timeframe during which something has started extends until now, the present perfect is appropriate. We know life did not start during the present time.

Comment: @Mixolydian I think your answer is much too firm.  There is nothing about the phrase "has started" that prohibits referring to the distant past, only common usage.  The way you answered it makes it sound like this is an explicit linguistic rule that must not be violated if one wishes to be grammatical, which is not the case.

Comment: @nasch fair enough. You could probably say "Life has started during the past 5 billion years" and that would not be ungrammatical, though it would sound very strange.